# use of ConditionVariable in constructor

Tags: java, android, multithreading, condition-variable

This code is used as part of a constructor to initialize the instance.
I'm wondering what's the exact purpose of ConditionVariable here?

My only guess is the calling thread wouldn't be able to acquire the lock to this class until initialization is done. Am I correct in my thinking?

```
final ConditionVariable conditionVariable = new ConditionVariable();
new Thread() {
  @Override
  public void run() {
    synchronized (SimpleCache.this) {
      conditionVariable.open();
      initialize();
    }
  }
}.start();
conditionVariable.block();
```

This is the link  to the complete code:
https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/blob/553a1d2ec15b3d34f76aff720d42de2f663eb55f/library/src/main/java/com/google/android/exoplayer/upstream/cache/SimpleCache.java

Comment: Without showing the code of open and block the best you will get is a guess... Also starting a thread in a constructor is smelly...

Comment: @assylias this is not a threat start in constructor.An annonymous inner class extending Thread class as been created and instantiated and then it is getting started

Comment: @KumarAbhinav - from where did you get that info?

Comment: @TheLostMind If you are talking about the Outer class ,then the thread may be an inner class as part of constructor.I was talking about the inner class

Comment: @KumarAbhinav - All I can see is an Anonymous inner class. And *assylias*'s question is valid. Where is the definition of `ConditionVariable` ?

Comment: @KumarAbhinav "This code is used as part of a constructor..."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's impossible to tell for certain without the rest of the code, but it looks like this is a slightly hacky way to run complex initialization code on a background thread but still have the main thread wait until the initialization is done. The call to `initialize()` happens in the background, but `conditionVariable.block()` waits until it's finished.

I'm left wondering what the point is, though. If the `.block()` call really does block, then it ties up the main thread just as much as just initializing directly. Maybe `.block()` does some polling but also allows GUI events to run or something. Hard to be sure without the code...